# Can I use the embedded hg command line in SourceTree?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I'm really happy that SourceTree has Mercurial embedded. On the odd occasion I would like to run an hg command from the CLI, like

```
hg status
```

To which I get

```
hg: command not found
```

Can I make modifications to my environment path to get the command line working for the embedded version, or do I have to install and manage a separate instance of Mercurial if I want to accasionally use the command line?

I'm using SourceTree OS X version 1.7.2

(This might be a superuser question, but I thought this community has a better chance of knowing and responding.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binary lies within SourceTree's bundle, in the resources-folder and is called `hg_local`.

```
/Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/mercurial_local
```

You might want to alias it somewhere else (like `/usr/local/bin`) and rename it on the go:

```
ln -s /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/mercurial_local /usr/local/bin
```

---

It might be a better idea to use some package manager and install mercurial from their repositories, eg. [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). This can be done within few minutes and you gain easy access to lots of other command line tools you might want.

```
# First install homebrew, than run this command
brew install mercurial
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the embedded hg files, Jens. I couldn't get the CLI working with a symlink or a path tweak, so I just followed your advice of installing a standalone Mercurial version for the command line.

Comment: Missing somethnig or is your symlink not renaming hg_local to hg?

Comment: You're absolutely right. Additionally, there'something weird with the `hg_local` and `mercurial_local` name. I'm not on a Mac right now. Do you have SourceTree set up and can verify the `..._local`'s actual name? I'll fix the answer accordingly, regarding both issues.